# Maintaining order of DataTable rows during parallel processing

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

Following is current piece of code:

```
 Parallel.ForEach(dataTable.AsEnumerable(),row => {

     // Code to process the data row to Dictionary<object,object>
     // Unique Column name is the Dictionary Key
     // ConcurrentDictionary is used for thread safety      
     });
```

Here I use `Parallel.ForEach` to process the row of a `DataTable` to an object of Type `Dictionary<object,object>` final result is of the type `List<Dictionary<object,object>>`, achieved using intermediate thread safe structure `ConcurrentQueue<Dictionary<object,object>>`, source of the `DataTable` sorts the data in a given order, but that is invariably lost during parallel processing. Since the order is important, so I have come up with the following workaround:

```
Parallel.For(0,RowCount,index => {

  int rowIndex = index;

  // Access the rows using the Index
  // Final structure will be of type ConcurrentDictionary<Custom>, 
  // with the RowIndex assigned based on original index
});

Class Custom
{
  public int RowIndex { get; set; }

  public Dictionary<object,object> DataDictionary {get; set;}
}
```

Final result of type `ConcurrentQueue<Dictionary<Custom>> customObj` is processed using following code:

```
customObj.OrderBy(x=>x.RowIndex).Select(y=>y.DataDictionary).ToList()
```

Following are my questions:

1. Is there a better way to achieve the same parallel processing, where I can maintain original order, which is a paramount business requirement
2. In final solution do I need local variable `rowIndex`, my understanding is `index` is part of Parallel loop and would not lead to closure issue

Any pointers ?

Comment: Why do you want to preserve the order? Can't you order the results?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Order is preserved from the data source based on a column which might not be exposed to the layers above database. Order Preservation for the analytical application we are building is an important functional requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this

```
var items = new ConcurrentDictionary<DataRow, Dictionary<object,object>>;

Parallel.ForEach(dataTable.AsEnumerable(),row => {
    var result = ...; 
    items.Add(row, result);
});

var finalResult = dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => items[r]).ToList());
```

Comment: Dictionaries aren't thread safe and throw exceptions when you try to modify them concurrently. This code will crash. You could use a ConcurrentDictionary to avid crashing, but neither that nor any other concurrent collection will preserve the original order

Comment: I can use ConcurrentDictionary here, this looks promising, let me check

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will change to code to use ConcurrentDictionary. Regarding the second statemant. The order ist irrelevant since eventually I use the DataTables row collection and only use the dictionary to get the results from the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You could utilize `PLINQ` with the [`ParallelEnumerable.AsOrdered`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asordered(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method that

> Enables treatment of a data source as if it was ordered, overriding the default of unordered.

In your example you could use it the following way:

```
var result = dataTable.AsEnumerable().AsParallel().AsOrdered()
                      .Select(/*Process the row to dictionary*/).ToList();
```

Comment: Would this work, when I am inherently converting to the different data structure like Dictionary in this case, I am not modifying the DataTable data. Also PLinq as I understand may not be a performance oriented solution

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I see no reason why it shouldn't work. If you are concerned about the performance, it's best to simply measure and compare.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj PLINQ and Parallel.For are equivalent. In fact, PLINQ can parallelize all its operations while Parallel.For will only parallelize the first step in a process.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Interesting article by Stephen Toub which suggests, why the Parallel.ForEach and PLINQ are not same. Parallel.ForEach is a lighter implementation when compared. @ Dzienny you may want to add WithDegreeOfParallelism in future PLINQ implementation.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/29/9655514.aspx

Comment: @MrinalKamboj be careful when comparing *different things*. PLINQ will parallelize partitionging, filtering, selection, sorting, aggregation. Parallel.ForEach will only partition the data and leave everything else (esp reducing parallel results to a single result) to the coder.

Comment: Agreed Developer has higher responsibility in Parallel.ForEach, but certainly these two are interchangeably used by many without understanding the intricacies of the implementation

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I wouldn't worry about this, unless your application runs too slow. And then you should profile your appliaction to detect the bottlenecks. If you are interested in code optimization I recommend you [*Introduction to Code Tuning*](http://www.stevemcconnell.com/cctune.htm).

Comment: @Dzienny In my understanding, in case of PLINQ, this would be an optimization step preferably applied by default, especially because we may not want to all data points queued up as a task beyond the system capacity, thus causing unnecessary context switching. Thanks for the reference though

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get Index in Parallel.ForEach instead of using Parallel.For

```
Parallel.ForEach(dataTable.AsEnumerable(), (line, state, index) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", index, line);
});
```

As i can see, the main purpose is to avoid OrderBy.
To achive this, create your before ForLoop

```
var lines =  new YourClass[NumberOfElemnts] ;
```

After this you can fill this list with any Loop you want. Lets use Parallel.For

```
Parallel.For(0, NumberOfElemnts, i =>
    {
        lines[i]=dataTable[i];
    });
```

Edit it according to remarks of @Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: I am not trying to avoid OrderBy, I need it that's why the workaround. I can't understand the solution you have provided, need to work on it to understand it better

Comment: Lists aren't thread safe for modification. You can achieve the same thing using an array